# SOLR: can hl.q override q=*:* while highlighting

Tags: solr, lucene, highlighting

i want to know whether hl.q parameter can override the q parameter when the q has a value `*:*`

**sample URL:**
The hl.q successfully override q=title:new york and highlight Empire state in the below mentioned URL.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=title:new york&hl=on&hl.q=Empire state.
```

But when the URL is like this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*&hl=on&hl.q=Empire state.
```

The hl.q parameter don't override q parameter and the highlighting array from solr is empty.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I believe the issue is that when you query by field `title:new york` the highlighting knows that it should produce highlight results for the `title` field. However, when you search across all fields, it would attempt to produce highlight results for all of the fields as that could potentially be very resource intensive on the server and cause performance issues.

In this case I would recommend adding an [hl.fl](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.fl) parameter to your request to indicate the fields for which you would like highlighting results. As stated in the documentation, you can specify `*` for this value if you would like.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*&hl=on&hl.fl=*&hl.q=Empire state.
```

Comment: Hi Paige, i tried your solution but i am afraid its not working.

Comment: Yes, I have been trying many different things, including the additional options defined in this post http://searchhub.org/dev/2009/06/08/bringing-the-highlighter-back-to-wildcard-queries-in-solr-14/ - but nothing seems to work when my main query is `*:*` I am thinking this is a limitation of highlighting.